# React Native : TabBarIOS and Navigation

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, uinavigationcontroller, react-native

I have simple app, with 3 tabs. Tabs are defined by TabBarIOS in index.ios. I’m not using Navigator nor NavigatorIOS. In each TabBarItem , I just put the component name in tags. Like this :

```
return(
        <TabBarIOS
        selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}
        //unselectedTintColor="yellow"
        //tintColor="white"
        //barTintColor="darkslateblue"
        >

        <TabBarIOS.Item
        icon={{uri: 'courses.png', scale: 5}}
        title="Courses"
        badge={undefined}
        selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'courses'}
        onPress={() => {
          this.setState({
            selectedTab: 'courses',
          });
        }}>
        <Courses />
        </TabBarIOS.Item>

        <TabBarIOS.Item
        icon={{uri: 'register.png', scale: 5}}
        title="Register"
        badge={undefined}
        selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'register'}
        onPress={() => {
          this.setState({
            selectedTab: 'register',
          });
        }}>
        <NavigatorIOS
          //style={styles.nav}
          initialRoute={{
            title : 'Register',
            component: Register
          }}
        />
        </TabBarIOS.Item>

        <TabBarIOS.Item
        icon={{uri: 'profile.png', scale: 5}}
        title="Profile"
        badge={undefined}
        selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'profile'}
        onPress={() => {
          this.setState({
            selectedTab: 'profile',
          });
        }}>
        <Profile />
        </TabBarIOS.Item>


        </TabBarIOS>
      );
```

If you see in code, in first and third tab, i'm showing content of the item by puting component name in tags like

```
<Courses />
```

But for second item, i tried using navigatorios to show component, but it shows only a blank page with title. it doesn't show the content of component. i see lots of examples working like that, but it didn't work for me. maybe because i'm not using navigator or navigaatorios for index.ios , because in most examples i see, they put navigatorios for index and set initialroute. i tried it, but didn't work for me.

[image: Register tab shows a blank page]

Everything works fine till here. In Courses page, I have a list view with items under it (actually items with header, which are collapsible) , when user clicks on each item , I need to redirect user to a page to show that course’s details. (I should pass some arguments also).

```
render(){

  return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1
      }}>
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
        style={styles.listView}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
  renderRow(data) {

    var header = (
      <View>
          <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
            <View  style={styles.textContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{data.nid}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.description} numberOfLines={0}>{data.title}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.separator}></View>
    </View>
    );
///////////
    var cid = [];
    var content = [];
    for(let x=0; x < Object.keys(data.course).length; x++){
      cid[x] = data.course[x].course_id;
      content.push(
        <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor='#e3e0d7'
        key={x}
        onPress={()=> {
          this.rowPress(x); /////  here i need to redirect user to another page to show course's details
        }}
        style={styles.child}
        >
        <Text style={styles.child}>
        {data.course[x].title}
        </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      );
    }
    var clist = (
      <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
      {content}
      </View>
    );
////////////
    return (
      <Accordion
        header={header}
        content={clist}
        easing="easeOutCubic"
      />
    );
  }
```

I want to redirect user to a page and show details, and i want to have a header title and a back button (like Navigator or NavigatorIOS).

I've found a sample app that is doing exactly what i'm looking for, but it's too complicated for me, that i didn't understand how it is working,
[react native tabbar-navigator (iOS)](https://rnplay.org/apps/nlsOOg)

I've looked into many examples and tutorials. i tried to implement their code into mine but it didn't work.
Also find some other tutorials using redux, but it's so complicated and hard for me. i'm looking for something more simpler.
[Navigation using Redux](https://github.com/jlyman/RN-NavigationExperimental-Redux-Example/)

Looking forward to hearing from you,
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Does <Courses> and <Profile > components gets rendered correctly in your tabbar ios? Only you dont get  your expected result in second tab of tabbar ios?

Comment: @SusylGhimire ,  Yes, they work correctly on first and third tabs. only in second tab content are not shown when im using navigatorios. but when i put the component name in tags, it works. 
if first tab, i have a list view with items, they are touchable highlights. i need to redirect user to another page to shows some details.
i tried adding navigator.push to onPress action for touchable highlight, but it didn't work

Comment: could you please paste your code here https://gist.github.com/ and provide for look.? How you navigate to another component?

Comment: @SusylGhimire  , sure, here you are https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6015b603d917ce744782ddd57beb2230

Comment: if you want to navigate to different pages, put navigator ios in Main page, here in your condition put navigator ios in courses page, from there give inital page as any component. And pass navigator to those component like <Component navigator={navigator}> . Navigator only navigates from its child components.

Comment: @SusylGhimire , thanks for your answer. do i need ton put navigator ios in index.ios also? and set initialstate?

Comment: Also, i dont get your navigator initial page <Register/>, where it is? you should import that component also. And the page where you placed the navigator should be the parent component.

Comment: @SusylGhimire i have imported the register component already in index.ios like this var Register = require("./register.ios");

sorry but do you mean by "page where you placed the navigator should be the parent component" ?
should i put navigator in index.ios or only in courses page ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116971/discussion-between-susyl-ghimire-and-ataomega).

Comment: Did you solve the problem? :)

Comment: @DavidGuan yes David, thanks. I will post an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that when i have few scenes and i want to navigate between them , best practice is to use Navigator or NavigatorIOS.

I continue my app and did few more scenes and components ( with few levels going deep ) and i found out that Navigator or NavigatorIOS is not working properly for that purpose. Then i switched to NavigationExperimental and that was awesome. Then i had some problems in state management, i found out about redux. it was not easy at first, but when i start it, you will love it.

So for newbies like me, it's better to start with redux at first. that would make life much easier for you :)